# Galleon issue withdraw from KT1 to TZ1

Tags: tezos-client, wallets, error, kt1, galleon

I am running into an issue with Galleon Wallet v0.9.4b on my Windows 10 machine.
I am trying to withdraw funds from my KT1 address to my TZ1 manager address.
I have tried using several different fees (low, medium, high, custom) but the transaction remains in pending state.
Funny thing is that when I click on "Withdraw", it say success but nothing happens.
Whenever I try to close Galleon an re-open it, the transaction disappears.
Has anyone ever run into the same issue?

Comment: EDIT: I found the issue. My TZ1 address did not have enough funds to cover the fees.

Comment: Please make that comment as the answer and mark this closed.

Comment: Please mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of transfer errors from KT1 accounts is that there is not enough tez in the manager account to cover the fee.